# Permission not working with new created controller in croogo 1.3.2

Tags: cakephp

I am using croogo1.3.2 in this i create a new controller catgories
and there are only 5 action admin_index, admin_add, admin_edit,
admin_delete and admin_process, now i go to admin panel permission
page  and generate a new  action, i have three types of role admin,
register and vendors, now when i give permission for access
admin_index of category controller to vendors type role and when i hit
the url http://localhost/croogo/admin/categories/index then it running
perfactly  and from here if i want to add or edit any category then it
show the authentication error, But when i remove permission from
permission page to access the categories admin_index action and then
hit the same url it nither redirect to me dashboard page nor goto any
other page the browser show the error of   "The webpage has resulted
in too many redirects"  and i already give permission to this role
type to access  dashboard  please tell me what i do so that if user
hit the url "http://localhost/croogo/admin/categories/index" then it
show the authentication error of you r not authorized to access that
location

Comment: You need to show some code for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: ok you can just add any new controller model and view then test with that you also find the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Run this from console:

```
cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync
```